# Difference between $\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x}$ and $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I don't remember lots of calculus stuff so how to prove this with minimal amount of calculus : for any integer $n\ge 1$
$$
\left|\sum_{x=1}^n  \frac{1}{x} - \ln (n)\right| \le 1 
$$

I only see that $\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x} $ is the left Riemann sum approximation of
$\ln (n) = \int_1^n \frac{1}{x} dx$ with rectangle width equals $1$ . But is there a less calculus way without the general error function ?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_constant) helpful?

Comment: Consider  that if $n-1 \le x \le n$ then $\frac1n \le \frac1x \le \frac 1{n-1}$. Next take $\int_{n-1}^n \cdots \, dx$ and add these up (with careful treatment when $n=1$)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank u very much !! but Euler's constant is the limit of a monotonically decreasing function so cannot be used directly to prove the above :( but surely you helped me find the answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Proven [here](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-euler-mascheroni-constant-4bd34203aa01) . $\ln(n) = \int_1^n 1/x \; dx$ is less than its left Riemann sum approximation with rectangle width equals 1 but greater than its right Riemann sum approximation with rectangle width equals 1 , this produces 2 inequalities , which can be rewritten to produce the statement in the original post .